# region conformally equivalent to pinched annulus

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm curious to see what the annulus with a pinch is conformally equivalent to.
[image: pinched annulus]

At first glance the extended/generalised [Riemann mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem#Why_is_this_theorem_impressive.3F) seems to suggests this is conformally equivalent to an annulus because it's a doubly connected region in $\Bbb C$, but I'm a little skeptical of this application since by removing the pinched point I obtain a simply connected region while if you remove a point to an annulus clearly you're not in this situation.

I was trying to think the pinched annulus $A_p$ as a limit of annuli where two points, one on the interior and one on the exterior boundary gets closer and closer and trying to apply the mapping theorem to them and trying to see if there was some clear "limit" of those annuli.

Comment: If the point is inside $A_p$, then $A_p$ is not an open set.

Comment: ah, is that what a "region" is in the statement of the mapping theorem?

Comment: Yes, a region is by definition an open subset.